# Linux configuration file libraries

Tags: c++, c, linux, configuration, file

Are there any good configuration file reading libraries for C\C++ that can be used for applications written on the linux platform.  I would like to have a simple configuration file for my application. At best i would like to steer clear of XML files that might potentially confuse users.

Comment: I think your decision to avoid XML is a good one. XML isn't really human readable except in an emergency.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could try [glib's key-value-file-parser](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/unstable/glib-Key-value-file-parser.html)

Answer (score 25):

I would recommend '[libconfig](http://www.hyperrealm.com/libconfig/)'.

Answer (score 8):

Another option is [Boost.PropertyTree](http://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/browser/trunk/boost/property_tree) ([doc](http://kaalus.atspace.com/ptree/doc/index.html)). It allows to read/write XML, INI, JSON and Info files. And you get portability for free.

Answer (score 6):

[Boost program_options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/program_options.html) This allows you to read program options from config files, environment variables and the command line. It is portable and very easy to use.

Comment: but this library could not save program options.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a simple config file, with a list of commands and/or variable settings, then it's very easy to write your own parser, so easy that it's probably not worth using a library. If you need something more complicated then the parser rapidly becomes more complicated and an existing library is worth using.

I've never tried using libconfig, but it looks like a good choice, and I like the format of the config files it uses.

You need to decide whether you want your program to be able to write config files. If it's a GUI program, you probably do. This will affect what libraries are suitable.

Answer (score 1):

For a single app, you could consider [libconfuse](http://www.nongnu.org/confuse/).

If you need to be able to handle a wide variety of config file formats (e.g. for a web portal for a system, which needs to read and write config files from many apps in many formats), there is [Augeas](http://augeas.net/).

Answer (score 0):

The question is what file format did you have in mind? The attribute "simple" is a bit of an underspecification.
If you are looking for a library that can use "windows .ini formated" config files you may want to check out ACE http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE/ .