# Functions for editing [section] key=value configuration files (freedesktop Linux)

Tags: linux, configuration, format, ini

I am looking for common functions for writing/reading key=value configuration files.
Perhaps something like the WritePrivateProfileString() functions for modifying .INI files used by Windows.

I specifically want to edit .desktop and .directory files as described by http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/desktop-entry-spec
So I need functions in some (C/C++) that conforms to the freedesktop specification such as preserving preexisting spacing, comments and UTF-8.

I do have my own functions for reading and writing such files, but I am not sure if my functions would preserve all cases in the specification, and they only support ASCII, so they are only suitable for creating and reading such files with the values I need (not for modifying existing conformant files).

I presume Linux desktops (KDE, Gnome) and file managers (Nautalus, Dolpin, Konqueror) use some common library .

I have found the following but I am not sure which conform to the freedesktop specification:

- Boost.property_tree (supports UTF )
- QSettings (Qt only?)
- ciniparser (read only?)
- gnome Key-value file parser (read only?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use ini file in c on Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280352/use-ini-file-in-c-on-linux)