# reading ini files using fscanf in c

Tags: c, linux

I'm having a problem parsing an `.ini` `file`. I know there are lots of post on this topic, and I have read many of them. my `ini` `file` have only one `entry`:

```
font=tahoma.ttf
```

Source Code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static FILE *ini_file;
char font[20];

void LoadConfig()
{
    char Setting[20],Value[20];
    int EndOfFile = 0;
    if ((ini_file = fopen("config.ini", "r")))
    {
        EndOfFile = fscanf(ini_file, "%[^=]=%s", Setting, &Value);
        while (EndOfFile != EOF)
        {
            if(strcmp(Setting,"font") == 0)
            {
                strcpy(font,Value);
            }
            EndOfFile = fscanf(ini_file, "%[^=]=%s", Setting, &Value);
        }
        fclose(ini_file);
    }
}
```

The problem is that, the value is not never read into the `font` `variable`.

Comment: There are only one line "font=tahoma.ttf" in my ini file.

Comment: Have you used a debugger to go through your code line-by-line?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to debug the source code, so I used printf("OK");

Comment: the algo is simple, split by line -> split by `=` -> shift the result, you get the key, shift again you get the value

Comment: But after compile the source code, I can see the message: "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".

Comment: It's all very well saying your ini file has only one entry, so why have a field definition? Tomorrow, you'll need another definition in it, and another. [Try this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280352/use-ini-file-in-c-on-linux).

Comment: I want to insert some new lines in my ini file.

Comment: Step 1: `while (EndOfFile != EOF)` --> `while (EndOfFile == 2)` Step 2 `"%[^=]=%s"` -----------> into `" %19[^=]=%19s"`  (add space and 19s)  Step 3 Do not use `fscanf()`.  Use `fgets()`.

Comment: Well, there is no changes..

Comment: 1) *LEARN TO USE YOUR DEBUGGER*!  There's no time like the present ;).  2) Your code has many potential problems, including (but not limited to) `char Setting[20],Value[20]`.  3) SUGGESTION: Use `fgets()` and ' `strpbrk ( line, "=")`, like user3121023 suggests.

Comment: If your platform supports `getline()` [(link)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html), that's even better than `fgets()`.  `fgets()` won't return an arbitrarily-long line (to be overly pedantic, neither will `getline()` - but `getline` is limited by how much memory it can allocate, while `fgets()` is limited to how much memory the caller supplies.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SefFault could be caused by the `&` before Value, but even after removing if, you could still read a *value*  longer than 20 characters. And some ini files can contain comment lines that does not follow the pattern and will break you progran

You really should:

- read line by line with `fgets` into a buffer of at least 255 characters - repeat until end of file : `while (NULL != fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin)) { ...}`
- use `sscanf` to parse each line and ignore every non conformant one:

  ```
  if (2 == sscanf(line, "%19[^=]=%19s", Setting, Value) { ... }
  ```

Comment: Well, I discovered that and allocated some memory for it. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

Use fgets to read each line in the file. strpbrk could be used to locate the equal and the newline and copy that span of characters to the variables.

```
void LoadConfig()
{
    char Setting[100] = {'\0'},Value[100] = {'\0'}, line[300] = {'\0'};
    size_t span = 0;
    if ((ini_file = fopen("config.ini", "r")))
    {
        while ( fgets ( line, sizeof ( line), ini_file))//read each line
        {
            char *equal = strpbrk ( line, "=");//find the equal
            if ( equal)//found the equal
            {
                span = equal - line;
                memcpy ( Setting, line, span);
                Setting[span] = '\0';
                if(strcmp(Setting,"font") == 0)
                {
                    equal++;//advance past the =
                    char *nl = strpbrk ( equal, "\n");//fine the newline
                    if ( nl)//found the newline
                    {
                        span = nl - equal;
                        memcpy ( font, nl, span);
                        font[span] = '\0';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        fclose(ini_file);
    }
}
```

Comment: I learned something new from you. Thanks for your reply anyway!