# Guide to good text file IO C/C++ on linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, file-io

I often find myself needing to write functions to load/save from/to ASCII (or similar) text files; such as config files or data. I can and have done so many times but never feel like I do it well. ie the results are not very tolerant of minor changes to the file format.

Can anyone point me to a good guide to writing robust text file io or even better some libraries to make it easier?

Comment: It's kinda subjective. Depends a lot on the file format

Comment: Your concerns are legitimate: its usually way easier and more maintainable to use an existing format with an existing library. Of course, it mainly depends on what your files are for (data is a wide term) and you haven't given any information about that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147902/linux-configuration-file-libraries

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Off the top of my head, there's:

- Glib's [key-value file parser](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/unstable/glib-Key-value-file-parser.html)
- [YAML](http://www.yaml.org/start.html)

Both of these are pretty standard under linux.

Answer (score 2):

YAML is a really good choice. Here we use [yaml-cpp](http://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/)

my2c